# The 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name

Tags: webclient

I try to send data to a webapi using WebClient.
Running my code gives an exception shown in the Title.
Can someone help me?

Here part of my code with the Header Definition

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = headerString;

                data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
                string contentLength = data.Length.ToString();

                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = contentLength;
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";

                wrCache = new CredentialCache();
                wrCache.Add(new Uri(URI), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user1", "f_k@1F7"));

                wc.Credentials = wrCache;


                byte[] htmlResult = wc.UploadData(URI, "POST", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HttpWebRequest`. For example:

```
private static HttpStatusCode UploadSharepointFile(string fileName)
{
        // Read file from path
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        HttpWebRequest http =
            WebRequest.CreateHttp($"https://google.com");

        http.Method = "POST";

        http.Credentials = (ICredentials) Program.cred;

        http.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        http.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        http.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) http.GetResponse();
        return response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Yes the error above comes from trying to add a header with the name 'content-length'.  Instead use the HttpWebRequest property 'ContentLength'.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content length property "ContentLength" by adding it to WebClient header as in below code.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    -
    -
    -
    //wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = contentLength;
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Length", 0); //if there is no request body to be sent
          or 
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Length", data.length.ToString());
    -
    -
    -
    -
    byte[] htmlResult = wc.UploadData(URI, "POST", data);
```

Comment: WebClient does not have such property, ContentLength is property of HTTPRequest.

Comment: ContentLength  is added as header to WebClient, please check the code above. Its wc.Headers.Add("Content-Length", data.length.ToString()); and not wc.Content-Length

Comment: Updated the description above.